# Converting Legacy Mac OS Japanese Encoding to Unicode in Windows

Tags: windows, unicode, character-encoding, cjk

Several years ago, Apple released a document that outlines the mappings between Apple's "Mac OS Japanese" Character Set and Unicode code points. (ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/APPLE/JAPANESE.TXT)

Microsoft provides the function, MultiByteToWideChar, to assist with mapping characters to a UTF-16 string.

MultiByteToWideChar works correctly for some Japanese characters in Apple's legacy character set (see FTP link, above), but returns "no mapping available" for others (For example, 0x85BE is supposed to map to Unicode 0x217B (SMALL ROMAN NUMERAL TWELVE), however it fails.)

I am using code page 10001 (Japanese-Mac).

Am I overlooking something obvious or is the code page for mapping Japanese-Mac to UTF-16 simply incomplete on Windows?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're actually calling to do the conversion? Passing `CP_MACCP` to `MultiByteToWideChar` will use the Macintosh code page for the current system locale. That may not necessarily be Japanese. It's not impossible that the Mac code pages on Windows are just incomplete, though. I'll bet the last time they were updated was when Microsoft was cross-compiling apps like Office for Windows and Mac (circa 1994).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment.  I called MultiByteToWideChar in a variety of ways including specifying the desired code page directly (10001) and by changing my system locale to Japanese and using the CP_MACCP value.  Both of these approaches yielded the same results.  After some more investigation, I think dda's answer hit the nail on the head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x-mac-japanese is usually treated as SHIFT_JIS by Windows -- and the problem is x-mac-japanese is a superset of SHIFT_JIS, so stuff will be missing. For instance, there is nothing in [the 0x85oo range in SHIFT_JIS](http://www.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/OBSOLETE/EASTASIA/JIS/SHIFTJIS.TXT).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Sure enough, the National Language Support file (NLS) for the x-mac-japanese code page on my Windows 7 installation (c_10001.nls) is identical in size to the NLS file for the shift_jis code page (c_932.nls).  Furthermore, these two files only differ at 372 byte offsets (out of 162,850 bytes) so it is exactly as you said.